# Check existence of a fragment using Robotium - Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, robotium

Is anyone aware of a way to check the existence of fragment using Robotium?

Regards
Rc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want to find the existence of a fragment that you know the activity or tag for.

first call `getCurrentActivity()` on Solo and then call

```
getFragmentManager().findFragmentById()
```

or

```
getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById()
```

if you're using the v4 compatibility 
library.  That will search all the fragments on the page and return it.  You can also use `findFragmentByTag()` if you've previously tagged the Fragment.

Comment: solo.getCurrentActivity().getSupportFragmentManager() is not working. It shows me "cannot resolve method" error.

Comment: Then you probably don't have the support libraries in your app, which is fine if you're only targeting more modern devices.  In that case, just use `getFragmentManager()` instead of `getSupportFragmentManager()`

Comment: I use getSupportFragmentManager() in my Application so have the support libraries.  I can't understand. :/